# Incorrect syntax near '-', using a script from LoginUserRolePermission.zip

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @SQLStatement VARCHAR(4000) 
DECLARE @T_DBuser TABLE (DBName SYSNAME, UserName SYSNAME, AssociatedDBRole NVARCHAR(256)) 

SET @SQLStatement = 'SELECT 
                       ''?'' AS DBName,dp.name AS UserName,USER_NAME(drm.role_principal_id) AS AssociatedDBRole 
                     FROM ?.sys.database_principals dp
                     LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members drm ON dp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id 
                     WHERE dp.sid NOT IN (0x01) AND dp.sid IS NOT NULL 
                       AND dp.type NOT IN (''C'') 
                       AND dp.is_fixed_role <> 1 
                       AND dp.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' 
                       AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') 
                    ORDER BY DBName'

INSERT @T_DBuser
   EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @SQLStatement

SELECT * 
FROM @T_DBuser 
ORDER BY DBName
```

I am using this code from the LoginUserPermission.zip file found on 
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-logins-databases-816f66b2.

When I try to run just this section I receive this error: (34 row(s) affected)

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

All the other portions of the code work fine. I tried to break down just the select statement and I'm receiving a message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '?'.

The crazy thing is the script worked just fine two weeks ago. All I had to do was change the database name and it ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your databases has a dash ('-') in the name. Put square brackets around your "?" parameters in the FROM and the LEFT JOIN of the query.

```
...
FROM [?].sys.database_principals dp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [?].sys.database_role_members drm 
        ON dp.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! Weird that it worked two weeks ago without the brackets. But it makes sense because the database I used it on before did NOT have a dash in it! Thanks again!